# Migration of Spring code by using Dagger2

Tags: spring, dagger-2

I have application written in Spring, Need to create Android application which can having same source code and logics. I need to use dagger 2 for Dependency Injection.

As i am very New in dagger.

1. Can we migrate all the spring related configurations e.g.@EnableWebSocket , @Configuration  (as I need to remove spring totally from the application)
2. any one have similar code example for migrating spring by Dagger.
3. Is there any direct mapping for the spring annotations with Dagger.